# Is there any way to get more detailed error reports from a windows API call?

Tags: c++, windows, api, status

I'm working on a pretty large program that makes calls to ChangeDisplaySettingsEx in order to change the layout/resolution around of displays.

I've been running into issues where these calls sometimes work and sometimes they don't, and I can't determine what's causing the failures.

Whenever it fails, I get a return code of -1 which corresponds to DISP_CHANGE_FAILED which clearly is not very descriptive.

I'm wondering if there's any better way to debug the result of the call so I can tell what's causing it to fail?

Answer (score 0):

> *"I'm wondering if there's any better way to debug the result of the call so I can tell what's causing it to fail?"*

You may try to query the actual displays capabilities beforehand, as recommended in the [reference documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413(v=vs.85).aspx):

> #### Remarks
>
> *"To ensure that the [DEVMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) structure passed to **ChangeDisplaySettingsEx** is valid and contains only values supported by the display driver, use the DEVMODE returned by the [EnumDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611(v=vs.85).aspx) function."*

After doing so you can compare the returned `DEVMODE` with what you've tried to pass as settings.

Comment: Well the big issue I'm having is I know I'm using a valid display setting.

 When I pull my code out into a stand alone .exe and run it it executes fine and changes the display, but the same code in the larger program returns -1.

This leads me to believe something in the larger code base is causing the Windows API call to fail, but I can't figure out how to trace down what this is.

Comment: @TrolliOlli How do you know for sure actually? Do you have installed a device specific or a generic driver?

Comment: @TrolliOlli: Did you try logging the content of the `DEVMODE` before calling `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()`? Maybe you really are passing an invalid/unsupported `DEVMODE` and just do not realize it.